# Convert one-dimensional lists to multi-dimensional lists

Tags: python, list

For example, I have two lists

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

I want to make a list c which in format of

```
c = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

Since I am new to Python, Can anyone help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip` (the example code is Python 2 style):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
print zip(a, b)
# [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Python 3 style:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
print(list(zip(a, b)))
# [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: @Akrios: Added Python 3 code. It's slightly different since `print` become a function and `zip` returns an iterator instead list in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want internal lists instead of tuples you can use:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [list(result) for result in zip(a,b)]
# c = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]
```

Comment: This is elegant

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = zip(a,b)
c = [list(k) for k in c]
```